# Found crack along where shower pan meets tile. Caulk it? Grout it?

Tags: shower, grout, caulk

Was taking a shower and noticed pieces of grout had fallen into the shower pan. But I couldn’t figure out where it had come from. Look along the bottom and found

[image]

[image]

I had redone the grout a couple weeks or so prior and it’s strange that the grout lines quickly started getting orange at the base. Is this cause for concern? Should I just caulk along this crack?

Another thing is this morning when I was showering, I noticed the shower pan creaking really loudly when I stepped on it. It had never done that before. But a couple hours later and there is no creak at all.

Answer (score 1):

The pan has a lip that goes up about an inch under the tile, so you are probably not going to have a leak because of the failing grout. This is a matter of opinion, but I think that grout looks better, but silicone-based caulk will probably be the solution in this case. You mention that the pan is creaking, which suggest some movement, and this is that is causing the cracking of the grout. Grout is not flexible, but silicone-based caulk will move with the pan and stay in place.

Comment: If the grout failed before, it probably will again, making caulk the preferred choice (unless one likes regrouting periodically).